# Kivy: how to set subclass property relative to parent class?

Tags: kivy, subclass, kivy-language

I am moving my layout from a .py file to a .kv file. However, I am having difficulties in setting the text size of custom label subclass as relative to that of its parent class.

The two custom Label classes are defined in the .py script as follows:

```
class BaseLabel(Label):
    pass

class SmallLabel(BaseLabel):
    pass
```

while the .kv file reads:

```
<BaseLabel>:
    color: 1, 0, 0, 1
    font_size: '20sp'

<SmallLabel>:
    font_size: 0.8*BaseLabel().font_size
```

However this last line causes an error saying that BaseLabel is not defined. How should I adjust this in the kv file?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that is to define a key in the `kv`, like this:

```
#:set my_font_size sp(20)
<BaseLabel>:
    color: 1, 0, 0, 1
    font_size: my_font_size

<SmallLabel>:
    font_size: 0.8*my_font_size
```